# Using Julia packages from a Fork

Tags: git, github, julia, package

I'm currently working on a project which involves the modification of an existing Julia package.

I have set up my own fork of the package on github and was wondering if it is possible to use this instead of the version on the Julia repository. I know it is possible to force Julia to use a specific package version using `Pkg.pin()` but i'm not sure how to force it to use my fork.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pkg cannot handle different remotes, but git can. Just add your fork as a separate remote in git, and switch branches.

Example. By default, `Pkg.add("MyPackage")` will add the original package under the remote `origin`, with its master branch as `origin/master`. So lets say we want to add the remote MyFork. Then:

```
git remote add MyFork URL
```

adds this. Now you can

```
git checkout MyFork/mybranch
```

work on that, do all your gitty stuff, and then go back with

```
git checkout origin/branch_on_origin
```

I find it is much easier to use GitKraken than straight git though. It's a nice GUI that will handle multiple remotes well. Github Desktop will not handle multiple remotes well.

Comment: `Pkg` can handle it with `Pkg.clone` but I'ld want to have multiple remotes for rebasing etc anyway, so would still likely do the adding of remotes, one way or the other.

Answer (score -1):

You can also clone directly from your fork:

`Pkg.clone("https://www.github.com/youusername/yourrepo")`

You may need to first delete the current version with `Pkg.rm`.

Comment: I'd strongly advice against this. @chrisrackauckas approach above is more stable and avoids short-circuiting Pkg.